# TinyMCE - Set Editor Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am building an auto-save feature for my TinyMCE editor.

With jQuery, I have saved the editor's content to my database and now want to load the content back in to the editor. I am having troubles with the quotes (") in the HTML coming from the DB.

My code:

```
var content = "<%=content%>" // Classic ASP variable containing HTML from DB
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

Example output:

```
var content = "<p>Oh yes, from Churchill, the <em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>dog</strong></span></em>.</p>"
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

In the variable, "content", there are double quotes in the style tag which is causing a JS error. How do I get around this? Do I replace quotes with single quotes or do I use an escape or encode function? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript has escaping functionality like Javascript (also ready if you use JScript as default language in classic asp)
Check out [**Escape**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [**UnEscape**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbb2yd2e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Following is an efficient way of doing to append server-side variables to client-side js block.

```
// escape on server-side, unescape with js
var content = unescape("<%= escape(content) %>");
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

Example output:

```
var content = unescape("%3Cp%3EOh%20yes%2C%20from%20Churchill%2C%20the%20%3Cem%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22text-decoration%3A%20underline%3B%22%3E%3Cstrong%3Edog%3C/strong%3E%3C/span%3E%3C/em%3E.%3C/p%3E");
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just HTML (no javascript) it is probably quickest to replace the double quotes with singles.

Comment: Thanks Beaverus. This is my issue, if my user has used double quotes in the editor article they're writing and I then replace them with singles, it'll look a bit strange to my user. This whole thing is confusing me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "<span style="color:black">Text "string"</span>";
tag_pattern = /\<.*\>/m;
matches = str.match(tag_pattern);
//copy matches array and replace quotes, then use matches array to replace into original string
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to BeaverusIVs first answer i have to add that the line

```
str = "<span style="color:black">Text "string"</span>";
```

should look like this

```
str = '<span style="color:black">Text "string"</span>';
```

otherwise the string is not valid and an error is thrown.